# sqlite3 exe shows SQLITE_NULL column values whereas on mac it is ok

Tags: sqlite

I have a test.db sqlite file that is created by a migration tool from ms access. The tool is found on this site: http://mdb2sq3.codeplex.com/

The sqlite file is read correctly on my mac. All tables and data are identical to ms access file. The problem is that when I open it on windows either by sqlite3.exe or by code with sqlite3.dll some columns contain SQLITE_NULL data.

I am posting the db: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4904447/khirapumpsshaft.db

for example in the kcomponent table on windows I get null values on ID_KCOMPONENT column.

**sqlite3.exe version: 3.9.1**  --> this is the command line shell precompiled downloaded at https://www.sqlite.org/2015/sqlite-shell-win32-x86-3090100.zip

**sqlite mac version: 3.8.10.2**

**OLD QUESTION**

I have a test.db sqlite file that contains some tables and a view (for test). The problem is that when I use sqlite3 exe for windows (**Windows 7 64 bit**) the view is empty but it contains data if I open it on my mac.

**sqlite3.exe version: 3.9.1**  --> this is the command line shell precompiled downloaded at https://www.sqlite.org/2015/sqlite-shell-win32-x86-3090100.zip

**sqlite mac version: 3.8.10.2**

the view:

```
CREATE VIEW TEST_VIEW AS SELECT kfeature.ID_KFEATURE, kshaft.ID_KSHAFT, kcompsections.ID_KCOMPSECTIONS, kcompsections.POSITION, kcompsections.KCOMPONENT_ID_KCOMPONENT, ksection_feature.DRAW_ORDER FROM 
(kshaft INNER JOIN kfeature_shaft ON kshaft.ID_KSHAFT = kfeature_shaft.KSHAFT_ID_KSHAFT) INNER JOIN 
(kfeature INNER JOIN (ksection_feature INNER JOIN kcompsections ON ksection_feature.KCOMPSECTION_ID_KCOMPSECTION = kcompsections.ID_KCOMPSECTIONS) ON kfeature.ID_KFEATURE = ksection_feature.KFEATURE_ID_KFEATURE) 
ON kfeature_shaft.KFEATURE_ID_KFEATURE = kfeature.ID_KFEATURE;
```

I have opened the file even in SQLPro for Sqlite and the view is ok! How is it possible?

**EDIT**

Just compiled from sources the sqlite3.dll at version 3.8.10.2 and it works!
([The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b) Visual Studio C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33347423/the-application-was-unable-to-start-correctly-0xc000007b-visual-studio-c))

It does not present this problem.

Maybe this is a bug of the last version of sqlite 3.9.1?? How is it possible?

Comment: How are you checking if the view is empty? You should be doing `SELECT * FROM TEST_VIEW`

Comment: yes, select * from TEST_VIEW;

Comment: Show your schema, test data, and expected output. Make sure the schema and test data are the same across platforms (if you can, use the same database file).

Comment: I cannot post the schema and data, but I can assure that I am using the SAME file

Comment: Interesting, even ``.dump`` outputs ``NULL`` values for ``kcomponent`` table ``ID_KCOMPONENT`` row. Didn't find any bug reports on that, so you can be first to report it, if you find how to report a bug. Bug search itself is here - https://www.sqlite.org/src/ticket

Comment: Yes you are right! If I could find how to report a bug :), it is a little obfuscated on sqlite site. To be honest I don't even know how to state the bug!

Comment: @Sanandrea . Visit this page : http://www.sqlite.org/src/wiki?name=Bug+Reports

to file the bug.